# C++ - What do these lines of code mean?

Tags: c++

I'm looking at some source code and don't understand what is going on. Here is some code I've put together from that source code (definitions came from all over the place and I've included only what's necessary):

```
#define TOC 0x1C75288

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef unsigned int uint;

struct opd_s
{
    uint32_t Sub;
    uint32_t Toc;
};

namespace Offsets{
    enum Address{
      GET_PLAYER_NAME = 0x421974
    };
}

opd_s GET_PLAYER_NAME_t = { Offsets::GET_PLAYER_NAME, TOC };
char*(*GET_PLAYER_NAME)(uint PlayerID) = (char*(*)(uint))&GET_PLAYER_NAME_t;
```

Specifically, what do these last 2 lines mean and do? :

```
opd_s GET_PLAYER_NAME_t = { Offsets::GET_PLAYER_NAME, TOC };
char*(*GET_PLAYER_NAME)(uint PlayerID) = (char*(*)(uint))&GET_PLAYER_NAME_t;
```

Later in the source code I see a usage of `GET_PLAYER_NAME` and it looks like this:

```
char* player = GET_PLAYER_NAME(0);
```

So is `GET_PLAYER_NAME` some sort of a function that takes an argument of an integer?

I'm just really confused about this and am trying to understand it, so if someone could exaplain the meaning and syntax, that would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like someone is casting a data pointer to a function pointer.

Comment: Last line doesn't look right. Are you sure this compiles?

Comment: Here's a nice site to decipher complex expressions: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: The short of it is that a struct with known values is reinterpreted as a function (or rather a pointer to the struct is reinterpreted as a pointer to function). To understand more you need to know what processor this is meant for, and probably what OS. Then disassemble the values.

Comment: `char*(*GET_PLAYER_NAME)(uint PlayerID)` is a declaring a function pointer.  This function pointer looks at the address given by GET_PLAYER_NAME to return a `char*`.  Presumably this is the players name.

Comment: @texasbruce the code is creating a fake function pointer. Highly nonportable. (Looks like MIPS.)

Comment: @raymondchen that makes sense. It has the same name as the enum member so was confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
opd_s GET_PLAYER_NAME_t = { Offsets::GET_PLAYER_NAME, TOC };
```

This declares a variable named `GET_PLAYER_NAME_t` of type `opd_s`. This is initialized to `{ Offsets::GET_PLAYER_NAME, TOC }` i.e. the `Sub` data member will be `Offsets::GET_PLAYER_NAME` and the `Toc` data member will be `TOC`.

```
char*(*GET_PLAYER_NAME)(uint PlayerID) = ...
```

This declares a variable named `GET_PLAYER_NAME`. Its type is: pointer to a function taking an `uint` as argument and returning `char *.

```
(char*(*)(uint))&GET_PLAYER_NAME_t;
```

This casts the adress of `GET_PLAYER_NAME_t` to a pointer ... see above.

This looks very suspicious as the contents of the `GET_PLAYER_NAME_t` variable which is a struct will be interpreted as the first instruction(s) in a function call via `GET_PLAYER_NAME`.

Answer (score 4):

```
opd_s GET_PLAYER_NAME_t = { Offsets::GET_PLAYER_NAME, TOC };
```

means create struct variable on stack with name `GET_PLAYER_NAME_t` of type `opd_s` and initialize it with fields `Sub = Offsets::GET_PLAYER_NAME`, i.e. `0x421974` and `Toc = TOC`, i.e. `0x1C75288`.

So, there is a struct named `GET_PLAYER_NAME_t` with `opd_s` type, which is equal to `{ 0x421974, 0x1C75288 }`.

```
char*(*GET_PLAYER_NAME)(uint PlayerID) = (char*(*)(uint))&GET_PLAYER_NAME_t;
```

It defines function pointer `GET_PLAYER_NAME(uint PlayerID)` which is pointed to former declared struct.

Actually `GET_PLAYER_NAME(0)` calls something with op-codes `0x421974`, `0x1C75288`, which we cannot know what it does, because we don't know the architecture it is compiled for (at least bitness and endianness of the architecture).

Surely it's not x86, DEP on x86 blocks executing stack data as code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how functions are called on PS3 via a prx module. This code runs on an external plugin know as a prx module. Think of it kind of like a DLL. You can load the game's executable into IDA and get the address of the function you want to call. So in this case, `0x421974` is being called. Since we don't actually have the game's source, you need to define the function like this:

```
char*(*GET_PLAYER_NAME)(uint PlayerID) = (char*(*)(uint))&GET_PLAYER_NAME_t;
```

The opd structure is just an int array which is specific to the cell processor.
On Xbox it would just be like this:

```
char*(*GET_PLAYER_NAME)(uint PlayerID) = (char*(*)(uint))0x421974;
```

Pretty much all it does is call `0x421974` which is `GET_PLAYER_NAME` on GTA5 and gets a players name from their client index.

The processor is powerpc.